# OK button behaves differently when mouse-clicked

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have a modal sheet with an *NSTextField* control, an OK button and a Cancel push button. The OK button is bound to an action method called *theSheetOK* in my controller class. I also bound *NSTextField* control to an *NSString* member named *foo* in my controller (File's Owner) and I use key-value bindings to read the text value user entered (i.e. model-key path of text field in the bindings inspector is set to *foo*).

All works fine if the text is entered and user hits the OK button via keyboard. When I trace the value of *foo* with *NSLog* in *theSheetOK* handler I see the value I just typed in the text field.

However when I clicked the OK button with mouse, the value of *foo* is logged as empty, also as soon as I click the OK button, the text field control grabs the focus and the text I typed appears selected. Any ideas what went wrong?

```
@interface MyController : NSWindowController {
@private
NSString *foo;
}
@property (copy, readwrite)NSString* foo;
-(IBAction) theSheetOK:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) theSheetCancel:(id)sender;
@end
...
#import "MyController.h"
@implementation MyController
@synthesize foo;

-(IBAction) theSheetOK:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"theSheetOK");
  NSLog(@"foo= %@", foo);
  ...
  NSWindow* theSheet = [self window];
  [NSApp endSheet:theSheet returnCode: NSOKButton];
  [theSheet orderOut:nil];
```

Comment: I believe a better solution than *Updates Continuously* is to 'end editing' in the action method that the OK button targets.  See this question for a example implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951255/cocoa-avoiding-updates-continuously-in-control-binds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you need to press enter to "confirm a change" to cocoa bindings. I'm not sure, but it's possible that when you hit enter both the change and button action are performed.

If that's the case, select your NSTextField and mark the option "Continuously Updates Value" so things get synced properly.

[image]

Comment: @Ergun: don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted (click the check mark under the vote count). That's the other way we say "Thank you" around here. It also lets others know when searching that your problem has been solved.