# Cocoa: Avoiding 'Updates Continuously' in control binds

Tags: cocoa, binding, key-value-observing, nstextfield

I have several panels that contain `NSTextField` controls bound to properties within the *File's Owner* object.  If the user edits a field and then presses *Tab*, to move to the next field, it works as expected.  However if the user doesn't press *Tab* and just presses the OK button, the new value is not set in the *File's Owner* object.

In order to workaround this I have set *Updates Continuously* in the binding, but this must be expensive  (EDIT: or at least it's inelegant).

Is there a way to force the bind update when the OK button is pressed rather than using *Updates Continuously*?

Comment: What makes you think that "Updates Continuously" is expensive? Is it? Have you profiled?

Comment: Well, no, as usual Rob, however it sets values in my core C++ library, which involves construction of `std::string` objects and conversion between `NSString` objects.  It just seems inelegant and I thought there must be a better way.

Comment: I agree, it's just that making assumptions about performance is never a good idea. Premature optimisation is evil!

Comment: Not true Rob.  When you've been coding long enough, you get a feeling for what is right.  The *premature optimisation* argument is rubbish - it's possible to code it efficiently first time round.  It's important to be happy with your work and coding something with no consideration for performance just makes me unhappy.

Comment: I don't agree that the argument is rubbish, I have seen a lot of over-complicated, over-engineered code used to address perceived possible performance issues that don't exist in reality. However, I do agree that it's better to write code efficiently. In this case I think you're right to optimise it, it's more elegant, but from a performance point of view it probably won't make much of a difference to the end user. However, since we're rapidly veering off-topic I'll leave it at that.

Comment: One reason you sometimes/often want to avoid 'Updates Continuously' is that when coupled to a CoreData back end, this means your undo manager unit is a single letter. Users don't usually expect to have to Cmd-Z every single letter after rapidly typing a paragraph. Another is that with NSTokenField/CoreData you end up with lots of partial token entries in your db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that you don't need to use the continuously updates value option.

If you're using bindings (which you are), then what you should be doing is calling the `-commitEditing` method of the `NSController` subclass that's managing the binding. You'd normally do this in your method that closes the sheet that you're displaying.

`-commitEditing` tells the controller to finish editing in the active control and commit the current edits to the bound object.

It's a good idea to call this whenever you are performing a persistence operation such as a save.

Comment: So does that mean you need a *outlet* to every control in the pane and need to call `commitEditing` on all of them before closing the pane?  Or is there an easier way to implement this?

Comment: You don't call `commitEditing` on the controls, you call it on the `NSController` that the controls are bound to. This might be an `NSArrayController`, `NSTreeController` or just a plain `NSObjectController`. If you're binding your controls directly to a model object rather than via an `NSObjectController`, then you should change your bindings to use an `NSObjectController` as the intermediary object. The chief reason for this is that the `NSObjectController` will use the `NSEditorRegistration` protocol to tell controls to finish editing, whereas a plain binding will not.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  This is new to me and not mentioned at all in the book I used to initially learn Cocoa programming.  I will look into this.  Is there a problem with using my approach (as described in my answer) or is this considered a *hack*?

Comment: Unfortunately there's not a lot of good information about Cocoa Bindings out there, and no-one *ever* talks about `NSEditorRegistration` for some reason. Your solution is maybe a *little* hacky, because you're relying on the modification of the first responder to do the right thing, which, thankfully, it probably will. It would definitely be better (and certainly more elegant) to investigate the `commitEditing` method.

Comment: As mentioned before the book I used to learn Cocoa programming was Aaron Hillegass's *Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X - 4ed*.  Using the `makeFirstResponder` method was how he 'ends editing' and not `commitEditing`.  I wonder why.  Anyway I will leave it for now - I have a whole bunch of code to write to layout complex text objects in another custom view to worry about first.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this is to 'end editing' in the action method that gets called by the OK button.  As the pane is a subclass of `NSWindowController`, the `NSWindow` is easily accessible, however in your code you might have to get the `NSWindow` via a control you have bound to the controller; for example `NSWindow *window = [_someControl window]`.

Below is the implementation of my `okPressed` action method.

In summary I believe this is a *better* solution to setting *Updated Continuously* in the bound controls.

```
- (IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSWindow *window = [self window];
    BOOL editingEnded = [window makeFirstResponder:window];
    if (!editingEnded)
    {
        logwrn(@"Unable to end editing");
        return;
    }

    if (_delegateRespondsToEditComplete)
    {
        [_delegate detailsEditComplete:&_mydetails];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is really old, I absolutely disagree with the assumption that this question is based on.

*Countinously updating* the binding is absolutely not expensive. I guess you might think this updates the value continuously, understanding as "regularly based on some interval".

But this is not true. This just means it updates whenever you change the bound value. This means, when you type something in a textView, it would update as you write; this is what you'd want in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment; however that is all it is; it's not an answer.